# How to get a unique modal header for each stock?

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates

I am trying to create a virtual stock market where I have different modals displaying information about each stock.
But the template renders as such that I am unable to get a unique modal-header for each stock.
[image]

Even after clicking on the 'CIPLA' stock I get "Buy HDFC" as the modal header.
Here is my django template.

```
    {% for stock in user.stocks.all %}
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <b>{{ stock.stock_name  }}</b>
        <p id="curr">Current price : {{ stock.current_price }}</p>
        Bought at : {{ stock.buy_price }}
        <button class="btn" id="buy" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#buy-modal">Buy</button>
        <!--Modal for buy-->
        <div id="buy-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Buy {{ stock.stock_name }}</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                      <form method="post" action="/stocks/{{ user.id }}/{{ stock.stock_name }}/buy/" >
                          {% csrf_token %}
                        <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
                        <input type="number" id="quantity-buy" name="quantity">
                        <button class="btn" id="confirm-buy" type="submit" >Buy</button>
                      </form>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

I have ended it with `{% endfor %}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is being caused by this line:

```
<button class="btn" id="buy" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#buy-modal">Buy</button>
```

As you can see, this line is mapped to `data-target="#buy-modal"` . This means that the Dom Element with `id="buy-modal"` gets invoked by it.

Now if you look inside your code, you are creating more than one number of modals(**but with same html `id`**).

The **root error** being the multiple Dom Elements with the same id. If you look at this line:

```
<div id="buy-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
```

this line is created n-times inside your Dom(because it's being run inside a loop). This means that there are n-modals with the same ID. This also means that you Dom has n-number of modals **with the same id**.

Now that's a wrong practice in writing html.

Every time you click on the button:

```
<button class="btn" id="buy" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#buy-modal">Buy</button>
```

the html parser looks for the respective `data-target` in your html. Which clearly are **n**(since you created n; more than 1). Now the html always invokes the first or any specific modal every time because it parsed only one while it initialized your modal. **Hence every time you click on a button, the same modal pops up**

So to fix this you have to create modal with **different ids and with different button triggers**.

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for being too late to accept this answer.It took me a long time to understand what you were trying to say.